# Entity MVC3 Seeding data with GUID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a user class that uses a GUID type as a foreign key.  I would like to seed data to another table that uses the GUID from the users class, but get an "cannot explicitly convert string to system.GUID" error.

This is the table I am trying to seed to:

```
public class Song
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Songid { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public string SongTitle { get; set; }

        public string Genre { get; set; }

        public string insWanted { get; set; }

        public string mp3URL { get; set; }

        public string wavURL { get; set; }

        public int? BPM { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the user class:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual String Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual String Email { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public virtual String Password { get; set; }

        public virtual String FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual String LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public virtual String Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
        public virtual int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public virtual String ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual String PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: What does your user's class look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happens because your Guid in User table is not being populated? Try using this PK attributes:

```
 [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```